# ios: modal presentation styles. Current context strange behavior

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have an issue:

two features I need:

- remove this controller with fading background black color.
- normal rotation.

First variant.

```
    modalController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    modalController.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

works great, but not at all.

On rotation strange animation (like this controller grows from center to fullscreen) appears.

Second variant.

```
    modalController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    modalController.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

works great, but not at all.

If I remove this controller, then, fading background black color doesn't work well.

How can I union these advantages and remove disadvantages?

I want normal remove with fading background color (first variant fit it).

I want normal rotation without growing from center to fullscreen (second variant fit it).